# Hyperledger Fabric Node.js Chaincode: Error: can't resolve reference Object from

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am developing a chaincode written in Typescript using `fabric-contract-api` and the IBM Blockchain Platform plugin for Visual Studio Code. My asset is called `Order` and, though tests pass perfectly, I am unable to instantiate it. The error I get is the following one:

```
[6/3/2020 10:51:34] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-Org1Peer1-06-chaincode-1.0.0|{ [Error: can't resolve reference Object from id Order#]
[6/3/2020 10:51:34] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-Org1Peer1-06-chaincode-1.0.0|  message: 'can\'t resolve reference Object from id Order#',
[6/3/2020 10:51:34] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-Org1Peer1-06-chaincode-1.0.0|  missingRef: 'Object',
[6/3/2020 10:51:34] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-Org1Peer1-06-chaincode-1.0.0|  missingSchema: 'Object' }
```

I think that the log is not clear enough and I am unable to locate the problem. I understand, as seen in other issues, that the problem is related to `fabric-contract-api` being unable to handle types like `any` or `Object`. However, I am not using that in my code. Everything is declared.

I have started commenting the code function by function to locate the problem and, for example, I get that error if this function is not commented:

```js
@Transaction()
public async createAsset(ctx: Context, assetConfigStringified: string): Promise<string> {
    const assetConfig: IAssetConfig = JSON.parse(assetConfigStringified);
    const assetId: string = await this.generateInternAssetId(ctx);

    const exists = await this.assetExists(ctx, assetId);
    if (exists) {
        throw new Error(`The asset ${assetId} already exists`);
    }

    const asset: Asset = new Asset(assetConfig);
    const buffer: Buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(asset));
    await ctx.stub.putState(assetId, buffer);

    return assetId;
}
```

These are the the declarations of the interfaces used:

```js
@Object
export interface IComplexType {
    propertyA: string;
    propertyB: string;
    propertyC: string;
    propertyD: number;
    propertyE?: string;
}

@Object
export interface IAssetConfig {
    propertyA: string;
    propertyB: IComplexType;
    propertyC: IComplexType;
    propertyD: string;
    propertyE?: string;
}
```

And this is the asset class:

```js
@Object()
export class Asset {

    @Property()
    public propertyA: string;

    @Property()
    public propertyB: IComplexType;

    @Property()
    public propertyC: IComplexType;

    @Property()
    public propertyD: string;

    @Property()
    public propertyE?: string;

    constructor(assetConfig: IAssetConfig) {
        this.propertyA = assetConfig.propertyA;
        this.propertyB = assetConfig.propertyB;
        this.propertyC = assetConfig.propertyB;
        this.propertyD = assetConfig.propertyD;

        if (assetConfig.hasOwnProperty('propertyE')) {
            this.propertyE = assetConfig.propertyE;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have found that deleting all usages of IComplexType and IAssetConfig I have no problems. However, I still do not understand where is the problem and how can I solve or roundabout it.

Comment: If you don't plan to make use of the metadata generated by the annotations, then you could remove the annotations. If you plan to make use of the metadata generated by the annotations then I would suggest raising an issue at https://jira.hyperledger.org under the node chaincode component

Comment: But what is happening here. Is `fabric-contract-api` unable to handle objects? I am using stringified JSONs but still do not know the reason.

Comment: As you are using stringified JSON for your input and strings as output you don't make use of the type checking done for a transaction. Do you use the getMetadata system transaction ? if you don't then you aren't actually getting any benefit from using the annotations. Have you tried removing them to see if it's still broken ? I can't explain what is happening as I am not a maintainer and have not used annotations. Your best bet would be to raise an issue on the hyperledger jira system

Comment: I am using stringified JSONs as parameters and decompress them once inside of the function and it seems to work. However, it still does not make sense to me.